# Re Captcha is passing null value after validation in PHP

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

This is part of my code to  call a second recaptcha for my php page. Recaptcha for first form is working perfectly, but this second is not passing value after validating the Recaptcha image.
Please help iam new in Web Development....

// this is part of index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var CaptchaCallback = function(){
$('.g-recaptcha').each(function(index, el) {
    grecaptcha.render(el, {'sitekey' : 'site key here'});
});
};
</script>
```

//this is par to of contact us page //
    else if ($f1name=="send"){

```
    $thecity=$ru['d_name'];
    $message;
    if(isset($_POST['description'])){
      $message=$_POST['description'];
    }
        ?>
    <script language="javascript">
        alert ("this is description : ");
    </script><?php

    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
    /* problem is here captcha is not getting value*/
    if(!$captcha){
      echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form</h2>';
      exit;
    }
<div id="popup" class="myoverlay">
<div class="mypopup">
<h2 align="center"><strong>Email Us</strong></h2>
<a class="myclose" href="#">×</a>
<div class="mycontent">
<table style="width:100%; height:auto;">
<form action="contactus.php" method="post">
<tr><td align="left"><label><strong>Description:</strong></label</td></tr>
<tr><td><textarea rows="10" cols="92" id="description"name="description" value="" required='required'> </textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my site key here"></div></td></td>                        
<tr><td align="center"><input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="send"></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the PHP?

Comment: sir, i placed only form part of the code ...

Comment: Could you kindly remove the PHP tag then.

Comment: Or add contactus.php contents

Comment: http://www.sadiqpoultry.com/contactus.php

Comment: Oh dear........